# CAP_FIRST function gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

I found this function for capitalizing the first letter of words in a string, but it is giving me a syntax error on line 8 when I try to run it in SQL in PHPMyadmin. Can anyone help me sort out what the problem is?
Here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
DECLARE len INT;
DECLARE i INT;

SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
SET input = LOWER(input);
SET i = 0;

WHILE (i < len) DO
    IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
        IF (i < len) THEN
            SET input = CONCAT(
                LEFT(input,i),
                UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
            );
        END IF;
    END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN input;
END;
```

And this is the error:
     MySQL said: Documentation
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Comment: did you define delimiter?

Comment: I picked up the code here: http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/ and I'm very new to all this. I don't know how to define delimiter.

Comment: For anyone having issues storing this function as I have had, along with @Spud (above this), check this out as it is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300902/cap-first-function-gives-syntax-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delimiter signals the DB engine the end of your statement. Normally it is `;`. But that would end the stored procedure at the first `;`. And its definition would be incomplete.

You can change the delimiter and add it to the end of your procedure. After that change the delimiter back to `;`

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))
...
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks for that. I'm grateful for your help and grateful for this site. I have learned a lot here and you just added to my (very limited) knowledge. Cheers.